# Reading .cer files from jar file failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to install client SSl cert at runtime. The certs are already packed with jar and is available in the below location
[image]

While trying to read all available .cer files from the above mentioned path using below code ,it got failed

```
 String rootPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("certs/"+activeProfile+"/").getPath();
 File folder = new File(rootPath);
 File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

while debugging I am getting "rootPath" as "file:/workspace/mnb-123-no-data-flow-trigger-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/certs/dev/" .But the list of files(**listOfFiles** ) is null.

But using the below code I am able to get the content of one of the file in "rootPath"

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/certs/"+activeProfile+"/server.cer");

            File tempFile= File.createTempFile("temporary",".cer");
            tempFile.deleteOnExit();
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            }
            displayFile(tempFile);
```

What is the error in the first snippet? how can I read all files from the path?

Comment: You can't use `File.listFiles()` to list files within a JAR.  It can only list files on a filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luke indicates in comment, Java `File` only handles 'real' files (and directories) on the OS filesystem, which in Java 7 up with "new I/O" (NIO) is called the 'default' filesystem, but we can now have other Java-defined filesystems including one that does work on entries in a jar/zip:

```
    String name = ...;
    URI uri = (myclass/loader).getResource(name).toURI(); 
    // I think Paths.get using ZipFileSystemProvider ought to handle the whole URI but it doesn't, so:
    String[] spec = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart().split("!/");
    if( ! uri.getScheme().equals("jar") || spec.length != 2 || ! spec[0].startsWith("file:") ) throw new Exception ("bad URI for jar resource");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("jar",spec[0],null), new HashMap<String,Object>());
    Files.list(fs.getPath(spec[1])) .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));
    // instead of System.out.println can do something else, or instead of .forEach .collect into a variable
    fs.close(); // or use try-resources to close automatically
```