# ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream() behaving differently in IDE and jar file

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, classloader, executable-jar

I have written following piece of code to get the list of names of files in metadata folder.

```
  public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream is=Demo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("metadata");
    System.out.println(is.available());
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(line);
    }

    System.out.println(list);

} }
```

**Here is the project structure in Intellij IDE**

[image]

**This program runs as expected in IDE and prints following output**:

```
22
[test1.json, test2.json]
```

**However, when I build an executable jar of this program:**

[image]

[image]

**and run it using `java -jar`, the output is:**

```
0
[]
```

**Why does jar file behave differently?**

Answer (score 1):

Real filesystems traditionally have (or simulate) directories that can be enumerated although the OS API and thus the implementation of [`File(with isDirectory true).list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#list()) varies by platform, and `FileURLConnection` (which is used for a resource in the filesystem) returns that list as the 'contents' of a directory.

JAR files are really ZIP files, and ZIP files were designed to store files not directories as such, although the files can have slash-separated names to organize them into directories. (Always slash, even though when it was created MSDOS and Windows already used backslash in the API.) Java `jar` creates a dummy 'file' entry for each directory, to contain the modtime and (I think) permissions to be used when extracting/restoring, but this entry contains no data, and that's what `JarURLConnection` reads for a resource 'directory' in a JAR.

You *can* list entries under a given directory pathname in a ZIP, including a JAR, using the (j7+) NIO ZipFileSystemProvider; see my answer at [Reading .cer files from jar file failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284646/reading-cer-files-from-jar-file-failing) . (And for real files such as unpacked jars you can of course use the NIO default=OS filesystem the same way; that's equivalent to the 'legacy' `java.io.File` class.)