# Why I can't use the URL path from the .jar file to detect if it's a directory?

Tags: java, jar

sorry for my English.

**My goal is to grab the directory in the resource folder of the .jar file.**

[image]

I was able to do it, by using `ZipInputStream` (open the .jar file as ZIP). But to think about it, I have to traverse almost every file inside the .jar and grab what I want.

Even after getting what I want, I cannot stop the loop until it's out of elements to iterate.

So I try to grab the directory directly by its path like this:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("/" + folderName);
        
JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println("url: " + url); // jar:file:/C:/folder/test.jar!/dir

File file = new File(connection.getJarFileURL().toURI());
System.out.println(file.isDirectory()); // false
```

I try many other ways by using either `URL` or `URI`, the `file.isDirectory()` always give me false, its not being recognized as a folder.

Is there any solution for this? Thank you!!!

Comment: Java `File` can only access a real file or directory, not a jar entry. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284646/ (my answer) and related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890530/

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you. I was able to grab the file and directories by using `Files.walk` and with your solution. But can I extract those files with the `Path` from `Files.walk`?

The `Files.list` from your solution only list the directories.