# Trying to include an image in a .jar exported file

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, jar

I'm creating a Java program with several windows (JFrame). One of them contains an image as a JLabel.
I have tried a lot to include the image in the .jar file exported from Eclipse , to allow the program to read them not only on my pc: however it doesn't work!
Basically, as soon as I press the button that should open the frame containing the image, nothing happens (this on the exported file, while on Eclipse it works perfectly).
I'm going to post the code, I state that I am just starting out as a programmer and I am trying to learn Java, but I am not too familiar with the subject yet.
Thanks to Anyone who will spend His time to make my request.
Richard

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/books.png");
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
JLabel iconl = new JLabel(imageIcon); // the images has been saved in folder images, that is located in the bin folder
```

Comment: You want to use `getClass().getResource("/images/books.png")`.  (Notice that the string needs to start with a slash when calling Class.getResource, but must not start with a slash when calling ClassLoader.getResource.)  Of course, you also want to check your .jar file for an images/books.png entry.  A .jar file is actually a zip file, so you can open it with any zip tool.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895019/1831987.

Comment: Thank fot the answer, I solved setting the folder image to a "Source folder" of the project.